# unknown type name while compiling C program

Tags: c, compilation, arm64

I am newbie to C program and I use Linux odroid 4.9.277-122 aarch64 GNU/Linux. I compiled the C program using `make PLATFORM=gcc-linux-arm BUILD=release`
In my main.C it use twMessages, twMessaging, twApi header files and I got the following error.
May I know why it gives unknown type name in the header file and how can I solve the issue?
Is it related to the platform= gcc-linux-arm that I used while compiling?

```
In file included from ../src/twMessages.h:13,
                 from ../src/twMessaging.h:7,
                 from ../src/twApi.h:21,
                 from ../src/main.c:99:
../src/twInfoTable.h:88:2: error: unknown type name 'twList'
   88 |  twList * aspects;   /**< A ::twList of the aspects associated with the entry. **/
      |  ^~~~~~
../src/twMessages.h:68:2: error: unknown type name 'twList'
   68 |  twList * headers;
      |  ^~~~~~
../src/twApi.h:166:2: error: unknown type name 'twList'
  166 |  twList * bindEventCallbackList;          /**< Pointer to a ::twList of bind event callbacks. **/
      |  ^~~~~~

In file included from ../src/main.c:99:
../src/twApi.h:30:22: error: unknown type name 'twList'; use 'struct' keyword to refer to the type
   30 | #define propertyList twList /* A propertyList is a twList */
```

Comment: Maybe this program was intended to be compiled with C++. As the message says you should use `struct twList` for the type.

Comment: Or this may be a sign that tw, whatever that is, has a botched C interface.  If it is supposed to be C compatible then this error would be representative of an issue to raise against that project.

Comment: Comments containing `::twList` also point towards C++ compiled as C code. Adding some more information what this `tw*` thing is might help us.

Comment: @paddy, Thank you for your reply. I am not sure whether I can edit the library file because, the program can compile in 32 bit processor.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, Thank you for your reply. I can compile the same C program in the 32 bit processor (armv71). But in the 64 bit processor (aarch64), those library give error. One thing is 64 bit processor is a new one. Therefore, I am not sure whether the issue relates installing any package in 64 bit processor.

Comment: @Gerhardh, Thank you for your reply. ```tw*``` thing is the library to communicate with Thingworx.